# How do I get the Class from a bean that is going through an AOP Proxy?

Tags: spring

I have class **A** which implements an interface **I**. So spring configures this as a bean which gets injected to another bean of class **B** as a property. Class **B** code attempts to get the fully qualified name (package + classname) of Class **A** using the injected property [**i.getClass().toString()**]... This results in only getting the proxy name of the object **class $Proxy27**... I also tried **i.getClass().getCanonicalName()**; same results...

So, What could be the cause of this getting the Proxy name instead of the class name? i need the fully qualifed name

Comment: You should put your question ***in*** the question.  That way someone will be able to help you.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to get to the class name, do the following:

```
Class<?> targetClass = AopUtils.getTargetClass(bean);
```

Comment: same results :/ .. The bean i'm injecting implements Spring Batch ItemProcessor <I, O> interface. So using your suggestion i did AopUtils.getTargetClass(itemProcessor); which is a property of the class executing the code (BatchRunTaskListProcessorWrapper) which also implements ItemProcessor.. but this call gives me the name of the executing class (BatchRunTaskListProcessorWrapper.process())

Answer (score 1):

Seem like Spring wraps your bean into AOP proxy, e.g. to apply some advices or to maintain scope of injected bean (for example when non-singleton bean is injected into a singleton).

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
Class<?> clazz = AopProxyUtils.ultimateTargetClass(proxy);
```

Found here:
http://www.solidsyntax.be/2013/12/10/access-concrete-class-spring-proxy/